# Django apache managing static files

Tags: python, django, apache, static-files

It's been a month since I started programming in Python with Django. Recently I had to deploy my first app on an Apache server. Everything went well, except how static files are managed.

Definitely, django admin css is not working, and so does my home made css files.

A sample of my settings, including what is related to static files management
settings.py :

EDIT settings.py (10/06/2015):

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['foo.moo']

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'formulaire',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'foo.urls'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_static'),
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'foo.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test_front_end',
        'USER': '******',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': 'censored',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Current apache httpd conf (edited 10/06/2015) :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName www.foo.moo


        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

          WSGIDaemonProcess daemonschift python-path=/var/www/schift/
WSGIProcessGroup daemonschift
Alias /static/admin/ "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/"
Alias /static/ /var/www/schift/static/
<Directory /var/www/schift/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/schift/static/>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/">
   Order allow,deny
   Options Indexes
   Allow from all
   IndexOptions FancyIndexing
```

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

By the way, I have that error log that oftenly spawns :

```
[Tue Jun 02 11:59:28 2015] [alert] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=19643): Unable to change working directory to '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs'.
```

I don't know if there's a link with my problem...

I've read a lot of answers before, and tried to use them, but changes in settings.py / apache config were not enough so far. I also followed django tutorials with no results. Right now I'm a bit lost, because all the answers I found were different and were never using the same ways to set up static files with apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `STATIC_URL` is wrong. Given your Apache configuration, it should be `/static/` (and it should be a URL anyway, not a filesystem path).

And I don't think the error in your Apache log has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: Thanks, now I have another problem but that's better : now the server recognize the files. In the error log I have that :  [Tue Jun 02 14:02:25 2015] [error] [client (adress)] access to /static/style_head.css failed, reason: require directives present and no Authoritative handler., referer: http://moo.foo/schift/welcome/              That's better than having no log I'll try to solve that other problem now.

Comment: @Kaël  Well this one seems obvious - just re-read your apache conf, the `Directory` directive for `/var/www/schift/static` ;)

Comment: I also don't think you'll need this line: Alias /static/admin/ "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static" One Alias in your Apache config should do the trick as long as you do a 'collectstatic' when you deploy. The admin static files will be put under /static/admin automagically.

Comment: Thanks, I found how to solve the first one by changing "require all granted" with something more adapted. Now I have another issue : [Tue Jun 02 15:42:45 2015] [error] [client adress] client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/staticcss, referer: http://moo.foo/schift/admin/
[Tue Jun 02 15:42:51 2015] [crit] [client adress] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /static/style_head.css, referer: http://moo.foo/schift/welcome/

Comment: I don't understand why the error told "contrib/admin/staticcss", I can't find anywhere such a mistake. For the second error I read somewhere it came from my htaccess... or from my httpd conf.

Comment: Check FlipperPA comment above - you should not serve admin statics directly from the django package but use `collectstatic` instead (you'll need it for quite a few third-part apps anyway).

Answer (score 1):

For the working directory warning, what mod_wsgi version are you on? Looks like you may be using an old version.

For your static file access problem change to using:

```
Alias /static/admin/ "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/"
```

You need a trailing slash on target path if you are doing to have one on the URL path.

Comment: Done, though someone adviced me to remove that line. Still static files are not loaded.

Comment: If you have moved to use collectstatic, you still will need an Alias line to refer to where collectstatic put them. When you do that, it is important that URL and target directory, either BOTH don't have trailing slash, or BOTH do have the trailing slash. If you do not do that properly, that is why you see a request for "contrib/admin/staticcss" with the slash missing in the path. How about you edit the question and at the end now put what configuration you have in Apache.

Comment: I'm using mod_wsgi 3.3 with python 2.7 and django 1.8.      Question edtited with httpd conf

Comment: Since you have indexing enabled, what do you see when you go to '/static/admin/' in the URL? What files and directories, or does that error as well?

Comment: When I go to 'foo/schift/welcome/static/admin/' I'm seing an index of my static repository, with js, css and img repositories inside. I had to manually set up an URL. I had this by setting 

url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True})

in my url views as I read somewhere it could be the problem, though still not loading css files.

Comment: By setting up such a view you now have Django serving the static files and are not using Apache. Did you fix up STATIC_URL like someone else told you to? Edit your question and show what the current Django settings module config is that you are using for what you showed previously.